# Fix JSON that does not have quotes around element names

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this broken JSON string

```
    {
    sources: [{
        file: "/images/image1.png",
        label: "Cat"
    }, {
        file: "/images/image2.png",
        label: "Cat2"
    }, {
        file: "/images/image3.png",
        label: "Cat3"
    }],
    skin: "",
    size: "1330",
    width: 728,
    height: 410,
    preload: "auto",
    startparam: "start",
    other: [],
    config: {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        fontSize: 15,
        fontFamily: "Verdana",
        backgroundOpacity: 0
    },
    "sharing": {
        code: "265235EF",
        link: "LINK HERE"
    }
}
```

But as you can see the element names dont have quotes around them, meaning that when I try get infomation from it, it wont work.

Is there a way for me to fix it to turn it into this (adding quotes)

```
{
   "sources": [
      {
         "file": "/images/image1.png",
         "label": "Cat"
      },
      {
         "file": "/images/image2.png",
         "label": "Cat2"
      },
      {
         "file": "/images/image3.png",
         "label": "Cat3"
      }
   ],
   "skin": "",
   "size": "1330",
   "width": 728,
   "height": 410,
   "preload": "auto",
   "startparam": "start",
   "other": [],
   "config": {
      "color": "#FFFFFF",
      "fontSize": 15,
      "fontFamily": "Verdana",
      "backgroundOpacity": 0
   },
   "sharing": {
      "code": "265235EF",
      "link": "LINK HERE"
   }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Fix this regularly? In what kind of environment? Where does the improper string come from?

Comment: Your first code is valid JavaScript. Can you not put it into a variable and do `JSON.stringify(variable)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for example:

```
var obj = {
    sources: [{
        file: "/images/image1.png",
        label: "Cat"
    }, {
        file: "/images/image2.png",
        label: "Cat2"
    }, {
        file: "/images/image3.png",
        label: "Cat3"
    }],
    skin: "",
    size: "1330",
    width: 728,
    height: 410,
    preload: "auto",
    startparam: "start",
    other: [],
    config: {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        fontSize: 15,
        fontFamily: "Verdana",
        backgroundOpacity: 0
    },
        "sharing": {
        code: "265235EF",
        link: "LINK HERE"
    }
}

var json = JSON.stringify( obj );
console.log( json )
```

Answer (score 1):

use `JSON.stringify()` like this:

```js
var j =    {
    sources: [{
        file: "/images/image1.png",
        label: "Cat"
    }, {
        file: "/images/image2.png",
        label: "Cat2"
    }, {
        file: "/images/image3.png",
        label: "Cat3"
    }],
    skin: "",
    size: "1330",
    width: 728,
    height: 410,
    preload: "auto",
    startparam: "start",
    other: [],
    config: {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        fontSize: 15,
        fontFamily: "Verdana",
        backgroundOpacity: 0
    },
    "sharing": {
        code: "265235EF",
        link: "LINK HERE"
    }
};

document.write(JSON.stringify(j));
```